# Nowdays farmers are _____________ mushrooms

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> Nowdays farmers are _____________ mushrooms.

Options-

a. rising

b.grow

c.has raised

d.raising.

My Approach:

I am confused between these two as i am not able to differentiate  after looking at their meaning.

> rising:going up, increasing, or sloping upward.
>
> raising:increase the amount, level, or strength of.

@Edit

Also i found the difference here.Is it correct?
Source:
http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/raise_rise_raze.htm

Ans will be rising please correct if i am wrong.

Comment: Try to focus more on the fact that "raise" is transitive, and "rise" is intransitive. Does that help at all?

Comment: side notes: it should be plural "mushrooms" and "nowadays" is more usual nowadays ;)

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/de/definition/englisch/raise, definition 5.1

Comment: 'growing' is missing..which I think is the most appropriate one! And BTW, from where are you taking all these examples? Any source? Because '....farmers **are**....' and '...**has** raised' is very less likely to come from an authentic source!

Comment: @MaulikV you can refer this website http://www.m4maths.com/placement-puzzles.php?SOURCE=elitmus&TOPIC=Verbal%20Ability&SUB_TOPIC=Sentence%20Completion

Comment: Your last edit (#3), unfortunately, lost the _a_ in Nowadays - _Nowdays_ is incorrect. Also, _I_ is always capitalised, even when it is not at the start of a sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Raise* can mean "to cause X to increase some attribute, height by default".

Another meaning of *raise* is "to take care of so that it grows/develops" - you can raise a child, raise a business, raise plants in your garden, etc.

*Rise* means "to increase in height" - it doesn't take an object (but can be used reflexively).  It also never means anything like "to take care of" but can mean "to wake up."

Comment: So, in the meaning "*to wake up*" the verb *rise* can take a direct object, can't it?

Comment: I think I have read/heard something like *I rose him out bed at the crack of dawn* before, but not very much.

Comment: OK, but what's the answer to the OP's question?

Comment: It's going to be *raise* - because *raise* means *to take care of so that it grows/develops* and *rise* can never mean that.

Answer (score 2):

Your choice led you to dismiss the grammatically incorrect choices, and that is good.  Neither *grow* nor *has raised* would be a proper form to follow "*farmers are*".

What you perhaps missed in the dictionary definitions is that '**raise**' is a transitive verb and '**rise**' is intransitive.  One cannot *rise anything*, but one definitely can *raise something* (and that is suggested by the trailing '**of**' in the definition for *raise*).  "*Raise* your hand who understood!"

So, to answer your question, no, '*rising*' is the wrong choice here.